# Select all option is not working using radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

can anybody help me out with this code? My concern is why select all option is not working in this code?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

  <input type="radio" name="A" class="first" />1</td>
  <input type="radio" name="A" class="first" />2</td>
  <input type="radio" name="A" class="first" />1</td>
  <input type="radio" name="A" class="first" />2</td>

<input type="radio" name="all" class="allFirst" onclick="checkAll($(this));" />Select All #1
<script>
function checkAll(e) {
  if (e.hasClass('allFirst'))
    $('.first').prop('checked', true);
  else
    $('.second').prop('checked', true);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are mutually exclusive.  If you aren't over 35 or like old cars, then you probably haven't seen a radio with preset buttons....

Quoth the Wikipedia -

> Radio buttons were named after the physical buttons used on older
>   radios to select preset stations - when one of the buttons was
>   pressed, other buttons would pop out, leaving the pressed button the
>   only button in the "pushed in" position.